# Focus event has different effect on different browsers

Tags: focus, datetimepicker

I have two datetimepicker instances on my page. I have hidden the NOW button from one of the datetimepickers by setting display:none on its css for "focus" event.

The strange thing is on IE it hides the NOW button, but when I click on the calendar date, the button comes and goes (flicker). I don't see this behavior on Firefox and Chrome. Any idea why this happens and how to overcome this?

Answer (score 0):

Does it specifically have to hide on focus? If it were always `display: none` then you likely wouldn't have that problem.

Comment: putting it in css file will hide the button from both my instance. I am not particular about hiding it for focus event. I don't know if I was doing it wrongly I couldn't get it to work by selecting this instance...How do I select the NOW button of one specific instance and apply display:none to it

Comment: so your problem is that you want the button to be hidden in one calendar and not the other? if you give each one an id, say `#cal1` and `#cal2`, you can hide the button in `#cal2` in css by saying `#cal2 button { display: none; }`

Comment: This is how I have defined..                                                           In html...
<input id="sDt" type="text" title="xxxx" readonly="true">
<input id="tDt" type="text" title="xxxx" readonly="true">

in js code...
$('#sDt').datetimepicker({....}

$('#tDt').datetimepicker({....}

in css

#sDt button.ui-datepicker-current {display: none;}   - this does not seem to work

Comment: that's how you have it defined? you said it was only `display: none` in the case of a calendar that has focus...

Comment: hiding it on focus is I have it implemented where I am facing the problem mentioned here...but I did try out the way you had suggested...but it did not work for me

Comment: at this point it might be helpful to have some code to look at

Comment: there is not much code...everything is the same as I mentioned before, except there is no css change and I have added hide on focus       $('#sDt').focus( function () {
              $('.ui-datepicker-current' ).css('display','none');
           });